# How to get event log from alarm central system?

Tags: c#, alarm

I want to ask, do someboady know how can i get an event log from alarm control of Satel?

I actually found sample code how to get detectors signals by TCP and it's like these:

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
{
    await client.ConnectAsync(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IP"], WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PORT"]);
    using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
    {
        byte[] request = EthmFrame.CreatePacket(EthmCommand.ZonesViolation, new byte[0]);
        await stream.WriteAsync(request, 0, request.Length); 
        byte[] response = new byte[4096];
        int n = await stream.ReadAsync(response, 0, response.Length);
        if (n > 2 && response[0] == 254 && response[1] == 254 && response[n - 1] == 13)
        {
            Array.Clear(ZoneBitStatusFlag, 0, ZoneBitStatusFlag.Length);
            EthmUtils.SetZonesBitFlag(response, ZoneBitStatusFlag);
            for (int i = 0; i < ZoneBitStatusFlag.Length; i++)
            {
                if (det[i] != null)
                {
                    det[i].IsAlarm = ZoneBitStatusFlag[i] != 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But i dont know how to get an event log that i saw on the one of producer programs.

> The event in producer program looks lika that: [EventListOfGUARDXSatel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBaCD.png)
> I tryed to change the EthmCommand but it not helped because i dont see any command that will do that.
> Thanks for any help.